# How to pass key of a value into variable in HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, key

Can I pass a key of a value into variable in hashmap?
For example I have a key 987456321 for value "A". How to pass the key in a variable so that I can further subdivide the key and print it as `987-654-321`,

- by taking `987` as first,
- `654` as middle,
- `321` as last 
  So that I can print

  > **first**+ **"-"** + **middle**+ **"-"** + **last** as **987-654-321**

by using toString() method.
I am new to Java, So help me Please

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    HashMap<Long, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    hashMap.put(987456321L, "A");
    hashMap.put(321654998L, "B");
    hashMap.put(874563210L, "C");
    hashMap.put(987453216L, "B");
    hashMap.put(321650123L, "C");
    hashMap.put(874568745L, "C");

    System.out.println("Size of Map:"+hashMap.size());

    System.out.println("Enter no: ");
    userInput = new Scanner(System.in); 
    no = userInput.nextLong();
    String name = hashMap.get(no);
    System.out.println(name);

    for (Map.Entry<Long, String> entry : hashMap.entrySet()) 
    {
        String key = entry.getKey().toString();
        String value = entry.getValue();
        System.out.println("name " + value + "- Number " + key);
    }

}
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: It is not quite clear what you actually want to achieve. What does "pass the key in a variable" even mean?

Comment: I guess he want to get key from map by value and put it into variable

Comment: Does your map contain e.g values "A" for two different keys ?

Comment: Simply iterate the map and do what ever with keys

Comment: Yes I have values "A" for two different keys @RafałSokalski

Comment: After your edit it looks like you already have the keys assigned to a variable inside your loop. So what is your actual problem now? The formatting of the key as String?

Comment: @dpr Actually,when I give the keyboard input of the value say "B" I need to get corresponding keys of "B" and pass them into a variable so that I can apply

Comment: @dpr So that I can apply the logic n=987654321, n%100000=last, n/100000=x, x%1000=middle, x/1000=first ; to print the keys as 987-654-321. I don't want to print all the keys and values. Is it clear??

Comment: I think in the answers below you got all the information you need. Simply check if `value ` equals `name` and you can apply the formatting logic. Apart from that the above logic won't result in the desired output.

Comment: @Pradeepthimareedu, have you been able to solve your problem? If yes, and none of the answers is correct, you can answer your own question and mark this question as solved. This will help others stumbling over similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over all key-value-pairs of your map like this:

```
for (final Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
  String key = entry.getKey();
  String value = entry.getValue();
  // do whatever you need to do with key
}
```

If you're interested in a key for a certain value only - makes not much sense as the same value might be stored in a map with different keys - you will need to check for the value in the above loop until you found the key-value-pair of interest. E.g.:

```
if (Objects.equals(value, "A")) {
  // do something with the key for value "A"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. Solution for specific value:**

This method returns keys for your value

```
 public static <T, E> Set<T> getKeysByValue(Map<T, E> map, E value) {
        Set<T> keys = new HashSet<T>();
        for (Entry<T, E> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            if (Objects.equals(value, entry.getValue())) {
                keys.add(entry.getKey());
            }
        }
        return keys;
    }
```

Now all you have to do is to iterate through returned set and do what you want with variable which contains your key

```
for (Long key : set) {
    String s = String.valueOf(key);
}
```